# When two curves touch, their tangent lines are the same.

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

So i am looking for a proof of this claim. I am not even sure how to start because I do not know what the rigorous definition of "touch" is. But by drawing a picture i can see that it is when two curves have a single intersection point and then kind of go into different directions. But I do not know how to formalize this. Is the definition "an intersection point where the two curves have equal tangents"? I think i am struggling to even articulate what i am asking.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe define "touch" to mean "has the same tangent line".  Then there is nothing to prove!  You are correct that you cannot prove anything about a concept without knowing its definition.

Comment: This apparent sense of "touch" is not the usual use in English, I think, certainly not without modifier something like "to second order" or some other remark indicating that they don't just _intersect_ at that point, but match up to some higher degree.

Comment: Well i want the intuitive geometric interpretation to match up with the deifnition. But i think i got it thanks to Umberto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but if you are looking at graphs of real valued-functions, you could describe the graphs of $f$ and $g$ as "touching" at a point $x_0$ if there is a neighborhood $I$ of $x_0$ with the property that $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x \in I$ and $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$. Thus the graphs intersect but can't "cross" as the value of $g$ never exceeds that of $f$.

Interestingly if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable  and their graphs touch at $x_0$ in this sense then it must follow that $f'(x_0) = g'(x_0)$ simply because $f - g$ attains its minimum value at $x_0$.

I never though about an analogy to space curves but now I'm curious.

Comment: So the definition is that they intersect once, then in some small neighborhood the relation $f(x)>g(x)$ stays the same.

Comment: I'd say they intersect at least once, since strict inequality is never mentioned.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Great Answer!!!